# Load angularjs app dynamically inside a bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, laravel

I have a page, `index.blade.php`. (no angularjs)

```
<body>
    <table>
        <!-- If i click on a row, I store its id in a global variable (selected_id), 
              then I can click on show_edit_modal to view its details -->
        <tr></tr> 
        <tr></tr>
    </table>
    <button id="show_edit_modal">Show Modal</button>
    <div id="edit_modal">
      <!-- empty at first -->
    </div>
    $('#show_edit_modal').click(function(){
       // Fetch view
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/get_edit/' + selected_id,
            success: function(response) {
                $('#edit_modal').html(response);
            }
        }); 
    });
</body>
```

Click on “Add” button -> it will display a modal.

An ajax request will be sent on click to fetch the view (edit.blade.php) to be placed inside that modal. Not using an iframe. The request will return a view/blade file.

In the controller, receiver of ajax request:

```
$data = Model::find($id);

return view('edit', compact('data'));
```

edit.blade.php

```
<div ng-app="itemsModule">
    <div ng-controller="editController">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
<script src="angular.min.js">
<script src="/controllers/edit.js">
```

That fetched view has an angularjs app in it. The angularjs library script, controller script, all loaded inside that view.

Is this possible? If so, is there a standard way of doing it? Or should I try restructuring?

I have tried to run this and it works on the first click, but when I click on a different row and try to edit the details, I get a warning about attempting to load angularjs more than once.

Comment: Add angular.min.js to your index, not the edit blade.

Comment: @aynber where will i place it?

Comment: Anywhere in the index that won't get overwritten, where you place the rest of your javascript. The key here is to load angularjs only once. It won't be used until you reference it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using [AngularJS manual bootstrapping](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap).

I moved the `angular.min.js` to my `index.blade.php`.

Then, in my `edit.blade.php`:

```
<div id="helloApp">
    I am an angular app
    <div ng-controller="editController">
        Mighty controller
        <span ng-cloak>@{{message}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var ang = angular.module('itemsModule', []);
    ang.controller('editController', function($scope, $http){
        console.log('init edit controller');
        $scope.message = 'hello';
    });

    angular.element(function() {
        angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('helloApp'), ['itemsModule']);
      });
</script>
```